# Sup Norm $|| x||_∞$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

If $X,Y \in \mathbb R^P \ with \ p\in \mathbb N
$

Is true that $|X \cdot Y| \leq  || x||_∞ || y||_∞ ?  $

I know that

$|| x||_∞= Sup( |x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_n|) $

I don't know how to start this excercise, thank you for your help!!

Comment: do you mean $\mathbb R^p$ with $p\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: A counterexample would be $p=2$ and 
$$X=Y=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: It becomes true if you modify the inequality by factor. Namely, $\vert X\cdot Y\vert \leq p \Vert X\Vert_\infty \cdot \Vert Y\Vert_\infty$. Note that this inequality is sharp as you can take $X=Y=(1, \dots, 1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counterexample would be $p=2$ and 
$$X=Y=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
since then $X\cdot Y=2$ and $\|x\|_\infty\|y\|_\infty=1$.
So it is not necessarily true that $|X\cdot Y|\leq\|x\|_\infty\|y\|_\infty$.